# Unable to log event: analytics library is missing

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send push notifications and they are being sent. However I see the message below in the debug console every time a message is received.

`W/FirebaseMessaging( 6134): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing`

Can someone advise on how to get rid of this error message?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Installing the firebase_analytics plugin for flutter as outlined in the link below resolved the issue.

[Firebase Flutter Analytics Overview](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/overview).

Comment: Thanks it works, just I had to terminate and restart the app as well.

Comment: I am also facing the same error.Where ro I have to use the flutter analytic

Answer (score 1):

1. `flutter pub add firebase_analytics`
2. flutter run
3. access firebase analytics plugin by importing it in your dart code

import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';

4. Create a new Firebase Analytics instance by accessing the instance property on FirebaseAnalytics

FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;